# GNU gettext tools not found on fedora

Tags: fedora, gettext, build-error

While build an image I am getting an error: GNU gettext tools not found : required for intltool.

I have done `# yum install gettext` and it says all latest versions are already installed.
Nothing to do.

how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install development package of `getttext` if you want to build another package against it:

```
dnf install gettext-devel intltool
```

Also using `dnf` is preferred these days, since yum is deprecated.

Comment: Did not solve the issue, I am still having getting the same error.

Comment: Try to install `intltool` too